# CodeIgniter: Simple way to validate a variable that depends on other submitted variable

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, refactoring

I have a form that asks a user how long they are planning to stay. I have two fields: number of the stay and the unit of this number i.e. 5 days, 1 week and so on.

I pass two variables: `value_stay` and `unit_stay`.

I want to validate them with the special business rules such as "maximum of 3 months of stay is allowed":

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('unit_stay', 'stay unit', 'trim|required');
if(isset($_POST['unit_stay'])) {
    if($_POST['unit_stay'] === 'month') {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('value_stay', 'stay value', 'less_than_equal_to[3]');
    }
}
$this->form_validation->set_rules('value_stay', 'stay value', 'trim|required|integer|greater_than_equal_to[1]');
```

My problem is that I have redundant check for `value_stay`. **And the second `set_rules()` overrides the one in the conditions**.

In the [CI Form Validation documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) there is no recommendation for such dependencies.

Do you guys have special tricks to refactor this kind of special validation? Specifically if the validation for `value_stay` that depends on `value_unit` can be shortened into a more compact and un-redundant hack compared to what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback function:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Your callback function might be something like:
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('value_stay', 'stay value', 'trim|required|callback_stayToUnitCheck')

Then in the same controller:

```
private function stayToUnitCheck($stay)
{
    $results = FALSE;
    // get the units
    // you have to get this additional one from the post variable
    if(!empty($_POST['unit_stay'])) 
    {
         $unit = $_POST['unit_stay'];
         switch ($stay)
         {
               case 'month':
                   // do your test on stay and unit
                   if ($unit <= 3) $result = TRUE;
                   break;
               case 'week':
                   // more tests
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Callbacks are very powerful when you get the hang of them. You can even set different messages for the callback error too:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('stayToUnitCheck', 'For a stay of months you can only book a maximum of three months at a time.');
```

Which you can set within the switch for each different kind of stay, or use a default message when a case is not matched.

Hope that helps,

Paul.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. Do you recommend the use of `$_POST` over `$this->input->post()` during validation though?

Comment: You can do the $something=isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL; or use $something=$this->input->post('something'); The latter being much more convenient. Other than that they are identical. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Thanks again for the concise alternative. I just read a post here that `$_POST` are not XSS-cleared compared to `$this->input->post()`.

Comment: Nor is $this->input->post, unless you set the optional second arguement to TRUE, ie $this->input->post('something', TRUE); but you should not be cleaning input (I am not talking about validation), you should use xss_clean on output. There are a multitude of reasons for this. Too much to go into here. Validate input, Filter output.